# Asp.net force https on some files

Tags: asp.net, https, web-config

In asp.net 4 I want to force https on some files, and then revert back to http on the rest of the website. With my hosting company I can use .htaccess and mod_rewrite but I've also seen various other methods suggested from creating classes to inherit the page from to the UrlRewriter httpModule.

Are there any particular advantages/disadvantages or is there a new built in method in .net4 that I have not found yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project automatically switched some pages to https and is driven by lists in the web.config.
http://code.google.com/p/securityswitch/

Answer (score 0):

in my experience, doing something like enforcing https is usually best done via the web server. You can create httpModules to do it, but configuring IIS would be better.

IIS 7 may have the ability to do this better, as you can filter files, folders etc in it.

Comment: Unfortunately on this project I'm hosting and don't have access to IIS.